# How to validate digits only with range 5-20 in javascript?

Tags: javascript, regex

I tried like below

```
function isValidMobileNo(mobNo) {
    var pattern = /^\d{20}$/;
    return pattern.test(mobNo);
}

if (!isValidMobileNo(temp)) {
    $("#spanRegMobNo").html("Only Numbers allowed and limit is 5-20");
    return ("Only Numbers allowed and limit is 5-20" + "\n");

} else {
    $("#spanRegMobNo").html("");
    return "";
}
```

but here I have to enter 20 digits but where I want to give 5-20 range?
so how?

Comment: Please check [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/95yqpdp1/1/). Is it what you need?

Comment: `/^\d{5,20}$/` will do it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use HTML, you can use the input number tag.

```
<input type="number" name="quantity" min="1" max="5">
```

Else, in javascript, the pattern "/^\d{5,20}$/" :)

Answer (score 2):

Change your regex to

```
var pattern = /^\d{5,20}$/;
```

Use range to allow from 5 to 20 digits.

---

I'd also recommend to use the same regex on the `input` element on `pattern` attribute.

```css
input:valid {
  color: green;
}
input:invalid {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" pattern="\d{5,20}" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not clear so here is 2 solutions for 2 cases.

If you don't want to use regex, you can also use this method(it's also check if it's a number-or string number like: `"123"`):

This example will check if the number length is between 5 to 20:

```
function isValidMobileNo(mobNo) {
    var numLength = mobNo.toString().length;
    return (isNaN(mobNo) && numLength >= 5 && numLength <= 20);
}
```

This will check if the number range is between 5 to 20:

```
function isValidMobileNo(mobNo) {
    return (isNaN(mobNo) && mobNo >= 5 && mobNo<= 20);
}
```